# Click on a select html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, cordova

I've got a Problem. I have a Select Option in HTML

```
<div id="eilig">
            <select id="eiligselect" data-role="slider">
                <option value="2" selected="selected">n. Eilig</option>
                <option value="1">Eilig</option>
            </select>
</div>
```

On page default "n. Eilig" is selected. After I have made a ajax post request (with "Eilig" selected) the select option should go back to default ("n. Eilig")

I have tried it with `$('#eiligselect').val(2);` but this only change the value back but the select option shows "Eilig" (but internal value is "n. Eilig".

This select is with a data-role "slider" which emulates a on / off switch like in ios. 
So I think I have to click that slider with javascript to change it back instead of just change the value.

Do you have a clue? Thanks.

Comment: can u give more information with jsfiddle

Comment: jsfiddle isn't showing the switch. With normal option field `$('#eiligselect').val(2);` is working well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : put `selected` attribute for option with `value="2"`

```
$('#eiligselect option[value="2"]').attr('selected',true);
```

Comment: No changes. Option with value 2 is selected but slider shows option 1.

Comment: See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/opoocgrw/12/), here default selected is 2 but I am selecting 1. Check if there are any console error.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event on change for slider on select value change,

```
    $('#eiligselect').on('change', function() {
        var activeLabel  = $('span.ui-slider-label');
        var mySlider     = $(this);
        var new2      = 'n. Eilig';
        var new1      = 'Eilig';
    if(mySlider.val() == 1) {
        activeLabel.text(new2);
    } else {
        activeLabel.text(new1);        
    }

    mySlider.slider( 'refresh' ); // .trigger( 'create' )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code may help you solving your problem,

```
var eiligselect = $("#eiligselect")[0];
eiligselect.seletedIndex = 0;
```